# Firestore "undefined name" error in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting an error in my IDE saying Firestore command an undefined name. I am making a flutter app. I ahve added the correct dependencies too. How can I rectify this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'FirebaseFirestore' in place of 'Firestore'.